# Laravel assign user roles dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, roles

For learning purposes, I want to use dynamic user roles in my application. For example, a super admin is able to create new users, and also able to create new roles, and assign roles to users. Right now I came up with the following:

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin:4']], function()
{
    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin:9']], function()
{
    Route::get('/admin/users', 'AdminController@users');
});
```

In this example, the integer is a user role. 9 would be the highest. Check out my middleware:

Admin middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    if ($request->user()->role >= $role)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('home');
}
```

This checks if the user has a role of "4" or higher, when wanting to access the `/admin` route. If so, they have access, if not, they will return to `/home`.

The above works, but the main issue with this is, that the user roles are hardcoded in my routes. Is there a way I can pass parameters to my middleware dynamically? If so, that is all that I need. So any pointers would be helpfull.

PS. I checked out another option, which I think would be better, but not sure. Using a roles table next to a pivot table as well, and then assign various roles to a user. So I would be able for example to use a multi select box to assign various roles to one user. And then in my middleware, check if that particular user has the role needed to access that particular page. Same problem though, how would I check in my middleware dynamically which role is needed for a particular page? In my admin section I want to be able to assign different roles to each page. Any thoughts?

Comment: instead of hardcoding the role number, just fetch them from db(use caching for performance) and than check against the user rule

Comment: I actually just thought of that yeah, I haven't done much with middleware yet so I wasn't sure how to do this, but it's quite simple. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Middleware would work but you should also check this if you're using Laravel 5.1+ https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization

Comment: Thanks, for now I created another table called `pages` and another pivot table called `page_role`. And in my middleware I am using a foreach to check for each page if the user has one of the roles, and if so, I return the next request. But I will be checking that link, thanks :)